# Android Status Bar Notification - Any way to make Notification pup-up (toast) over status bar?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am wondering if there is a way to make the notification pop-up above the status bar, like a traditional toast message, when first received.  As it functions by default, when a notification is received, the notification Ticker is shown IN the status bar and hides the other notification icons (if any are present) temporarily until the notification ticker is done being displayed.  Then, the notification icon is added normally to the horizontal list of icons awaiting user interaction.  I want the initial reception ticker to just rise above the status bar, then add the icon with the rest of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the `Notification` system, except perhaps via a custom build of Android which you modify to have this capability.

That being said, you are welcome to display a `Toast` in addition to, or instead of, displaying a `Notification`.

Comment: Ahh bummer.  Quick follow-up; is this the same for JellyBean?  I know they have made some significant changes to the notification system, not sure if this is one of them.

Yeah, with a toast, I would lose the pending intent capability.  Oh well.  Thanks CommonsWare.

Comment: @Mick0311: No, this has not changed in JB.